# Eu desabilitei a opção "rabiscos de erros" da extensão c/c++. Alguém sabe como ativá-la novamente?

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio, extensão

Eu desabilitei a opção de "rabiscos de erros" da extensão c/c++ no visual studio code por curiosidade, mas agora não sei como ativá-la novamente. Eu já procurei em diversos sites e fóruns uma solução para isso, mas não consegui achar em nenhum lugar. Inclusive, desinstalei e instalei o vs code para ver se funcionaria novamente, mas não funcionou (eu também apaguei as pastas do vs code que estavam no C:). Alguém saberia como ativar essa função novamente? Ela me ajuda bastante, pois sou iniciante e gosto de saber onde estou errando.

por exemplo, nesse trecho de código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int bcc;

    for(bcc = 5; bcc < 32; bcc++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", bcc)
    }
    abc

    return 0;
}
```

era para estar mostrando um sublinhado no **final do printf**, afinal está sem o ponto e vírgula, assim como também era para estar um sublinhado no **abc**, pois essa variável não foi declarada e está sem o ponto e vírgula. o programa não está compilando por causa desses erros, o que já era de se esperar, mas eu gostaria muito de ter essa função novamente que sublinha e diz qual erro foi cometido antes de compilar. De antemão, agradeço a todos que puderem se dispor para me ajudar.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nas configurações da linguagem e do compilador. Ao que parece, o visual studio não está reconhecendo isso como código. Essas indicações de erro sintático são automáticas na maioria das IDEs.

Comment: agora deu certo. Muito obrigado pelo apoio, Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

No Visual Studio code, abra a paleta Command (Ctrl Shift P) e pesquise 'Enable Error Squiggles' e pronto!